# Edit Java Configuration File inside WAR in Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat

I compiled a Java application into a WAR file, there is a configuration file inside the WAR file. The configuration file is required to change something after deployed to the production server, because it still contains the UAT server parameters.
However, I don't know where to edit the configuration file after deployed in Tomcat. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: What is preventing you from just redeploying the WAR file with the correct config files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't sound like a correct design. You should -

1. Load configuration file based on some System parameter (e.g. -Denvironment=UAT or PROD). This will be the decision factor for loading the right configuration file.
2. Do not package the file inside war itself, if possible externalize it to some other directory where amending is lot easier.

Comment: And make sure the directory where the file(s) are put, your application has access to it.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to externalize the file to other directory. Then, how can I access the file and modify it, by what kind of tool..

Comment: Bear in mind. A number of ways but depends on you deployments model. E.g. Define a static path and ready  configs from there as a static path. Just like how you read a file or properties file. If you want to resource a class path resource you can use paths that container by itself supports. Now for this you need to  be more explicit with you code.